# Are meaning and interpretation junk tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tags [interpretation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpretation) and [meaning](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), imho, aren't being used consistantly.  Or maybe I'm just crazy and they're being used find.  What's everyone think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anything, it should be merged/synonymed with [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) or even nuked.
This is because these tags incite discussion rather than an answer IMO.

Comment: interpretation and meaning are synonyms of each other at the very least

Comment: I agree they can be merged with eachother. I disagree they are synonyms of plot-explanation. Plot-explanation is about what is happening in the movie ("Obi-wan is trying to convince Anakin to not give in to the dark side"). Interpretation is about the message or statement the movie has about or to society ("I'm George Lucas and I hate George Bush"). And while discussion is frowned upon on Stack Exchange, not all subjective material is. Plus a lot of the interpretations has published and cited material you can reference in your answer.